# Javascript Counter - Skips number 1. Goes from 0 to 2 - Why?

Tags: javascript, counter

As the title suggests, I have a simple counter on a page.
Two buttons: one adds 1, the other subtracts 1.
It starts on "0". When clicking on the "add button", it should go to "1".
But it skips it right to "2". Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I have:

```js
    var count = 1;
    var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
    function plus(){
        count++;
        countEl.value = count;
    }
    function minus(){
      if (count > 0) {
        count--;
        countEl.value = count;
      }  
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()">
```

Comment: `var count = 1;` = it starts on 1, not 0.

Comment: The value you have in your input at the start is 0, but the value in `count` is 1. When you click "plus" you first increase `count` to 2 and then update your input.

Comment: Why are you not using the value of the input? Why are you using a variable?

Comment: I really do not understand the downvotes on this question.

Comment: @FreemanLambda Because it shows no debugging effort.  The OP has incremented a variable that has started at a value and is then confused as to why the value has incremented.

Comment: @zero298 as you said, he is confused. What is trivial to you might not be trivial to OP. He is a new user in SO who has posted a runnable snippet, that shows already effort from his side.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I am sorry for asking something that must be pretty basic and obvious. I am new to both Stack Overflow and Javascript. I am doing my best to learn. I will try to not make the same kind of mistake again.

Comment: @MikeMichaels don't worry about it; we've all been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When clicking on the "add button", it should go to "1". But it skips it right to "2"

```
count++; /* do this later */
countEl.value = count;
```

It's because you **updated** count ***before*** displaying its previous state

```js
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
var count = parseInt(countEl.value);

function plus() {
  countEl.value = ++count;
}

function minus() {
  if (count > 0) {
    countEl.value = --count;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()">
```

Another example where you don't require two functions

```js
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");

function add(by) {
  var res = parseInt(countEl.value) + parseInt(by);
  countEl.value = 0 > res ? '0' : res;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
<input type="button" value="-1" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="+1" onclick="add(this.value)">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I learnt a lot! I was not aware I could simplify it that way.